# Azure Static Web App ADB2C Authentication for Kubernetes backend

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-aks, azure-static-web-app

I am currently attempting to utilize Backend APIs deployed on Azure Kubernetes Service for my React frontend deployed in Azure Static Web App. The authentication process for the frontend involves Azure ADB2C. However, I am facing challenges in establishing authenticated calls to the backend APIs. The built-in Backend API for Static Web Apps is not feasible due to the use of AKS.

One potential solution is to leverage Azure API Management (APIM) to link to the backend. Unfortunately, using an External APIM would incur significant costs for my small application. As an alternative, I am exploring options to retrieve a JWT from the authenticated Static Web App or ADB2C and pass this token to the AKS Backend API. Subsequently, I aim to perform JWT validation within the API.

If anyone has insights or suggestions to help resolve this issue, I would greatly appreciate your assistance

Comment: Can you clarify your problem?
You should be able to use ADB2C to get a token for your API.

Comment: Are you using one of the out-of-the-box auth mecanism: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/authentication-authorization ?

Comment: I'm not using static web apps. However,  I do use ADB2C to authenticate clients for my APIs